# Python- Reading back usernames and passwords into a program to authenticate

Tags: python, file, dictionary, io, simplify

I am currently writing a program in Python that asks if you have a log in. If no, they proceed to create a username and password. If yes, they log in and their details are checked against a text file. The text file looks like this (Username then password):

```
whitehallj27
EXpass%20
Username2
EXPASSWORD%%%
james_27
password1234
```

I am trying to figure out a way of programming this as simply as possible. It seems to work, but isn't nearly as simple and doesn't really work how I thought it would. Here is the code snippet:

```
logins={}
usernames_passwords=open("UsernamesAndPasswords.txt","r")
count=0
for line in usernames_passwords:
    count=count+1
count=count/2    
usernames_passwords.close()
usernames_passwords=open("UsernamesAndPasswords.txt","r")

try:
    for x in range(count):
        username=usernames_passwords.readline()
        password=usernames_passwords.readline()
        logins[username]=password
except TypeError:
    count=int(count+0.5)
    for x in range(count):
        username=usernames_passwords.readline()
        password=usernames_passwords.readline()
        logins[username]=password

usernames_passwords.close()
print(logins)
```

Also, how would I go about authenticating the username and password to check it's correct.

Many thanks,
James Duxbury

Comment: I really hope this is for some homework thing, because storing passwords like that is a very, very, VERY bad idea

Comment: As mentioned by CBredlow, passwords are *never* to be stored as plaintext. Even storing an unsalted hash of a password is fraught with peril, but it's a good place to start.

Comment: I mean, if you're choosing to do this, why not store them as some sort of dictionary/tuples in the text file and read them in.

Comment: _doesn't really work how I thought it would_ Please explain what you want it to do, and what it's doing instead.  Don't just tell us "it isn't working".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that variables `user` and `passwd` have the username and password provided by the user, then just read the file in two lines:

```
file_contents = []
with open("UsernamesAndPasswords.txt","r") as f:  #use "with", it will auotamtically close the file
    file_contents = f.readlines()
usernames = file_contents[0::2]  #step by 2, take all elements starting at index 0
passwords = file_contents[1::2]  #step by 2, take all elements starting at index 1
found_at_index = -1
for i in range(0,len(usernames)):
    if user == usernames[i] and passwd == passwrods[i]:
        found_at_index = i
        break
if found_at_index >= 0 :
     #do whatever you want, there is match
else:
     #I don't know what you wanted to do in this case
```

Please read this for the [with](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) keyword and [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for how to read a file nicelly.

Also [this](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/) about the `[::]` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary with the user names and passwords like this:

```
dict = {
    'user-name': 'password-hashing',
    'another-user': 'another-password'
}
```

after you've done it you can save this dict in a json file, and load its content when the user asks for login.

the docs for handling json files with python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

obs.: it will look simpler, but its not the best way of doing this king of thing